# How do I make a AWS Cloudwatch Insights line chart plot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to parse a structured JSON value as milliseconds, that looks like:

[image: Exported to Google sheets]

Instead with my AWS Log Insights query:

```
fields msg, duration, @timestamp
| filter msg == "fetching"
| display @timestamp, duration
```

[image: No visualization available]

When I click the **Vizualization** tab it says "No visualization available".

Comment: Can you try it from CloudWatch Dashboards instead?

https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/a8e9c6a6-0ba9-48a7-a90d-378a440ab8ba/en-US/200-cloudwatch/240-cloudwatch-dashboards/241-cloudwatch-dashboard

Comment: Also struggling to make a metric filter https://s.natalian.org/2023-03-05/filter.png

Comment: if you are using json data then you should remove all delimiters such as new lines and carriage returns

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    fields @timestamp, duration
    | filter msg == "fetching"
    | stats avg(duration) as avgDuration by bin(1m)
```